# How can I get biblatex-chicago to be consistent about bibliography format for primary sources with editors? (Or is this a bug?)

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biblatex-chicago, chicago-style

Using `biblatex-chicago`, I often cite modern scholarly editions (some of which include translations) of ancient and medieval primary sources. For example,

> Theodosius. *Sphaerica: Arabic and Medieval Latin Translations*. Edited by Paul Kunitzsch and Richard Lorch. Stuttgart: Steiner, 2010.

For some time I have noticed an issue (perhaps a bug?) where `biblatex-chicago` seems to be inconsistent in how it formats entries for such works in the final bibliography (`\printbibliography`). Sometimes it formats it as I formatted it above (correct Chicago style), but other times after the title it has a comma instead of a period (and thus uses a lowercase "edited by" to introduce the editor's name. For example,

> Apollonios of Perga. *Apollonius de Perge, Coniques: Texte grec et arabe*, edited by Roshdi Rashed. multiple volumes. Berlin: de Gruyter, 2008.

(This entry has the additional problem that I would have liked `Volumes = {multiple}` to yield "Multiple volumes" -- capitalized -- here. But that is not what I'm asking about here.)

I have not been able to figure out the pattern, why it does it right for some but wrong for others. What am I doing wrong? Or is this a bug?

## MWE

### tex file

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes,isbn=false]{biblatex-chicago}
\addbibresource{a.bib}

% Arabic Transliteration (variations) - personal macros I use in the bib entries
\newcommand\iyy{iyy} % or: īy
\newcommand\aH{ah} % or: a [ta marbuta]
\def\iyyah{\iyy{}\aH{}}
\def\iyyuun{\iyy{}ūn}
\def\iyyiin{\iyy{}īn}
\def\iyyaat{\iyy{}āt}
\def\iyyat{\iyy{}at}

\begin{document}

\nocite{rashed.papadopoulos2017menelaus}\nocite{nasawi:tajrid.usul.handasa:mawalidi2016}\nocite{khayyam:riyadiyat:rashed.vahabzadeh2005}\nocite{khayyam:rasail:rashed.jabbar1981}\nocite{apollonios:conics:rashed2008}\nocite{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh2000}\nocite{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh1999}\nocite{euclid:elements:arab:besthorn.heiberg1897}\nocite{theodosius:sphaerica:ar.lat:kunitzsch.lorch2010}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

## a.bib

```
%% This BibTeX bibliography file was created using BibDesk.
%% http://bibdesk.sourceforge.net/


%% Created for Alexandre Roberts at 2020-05-30 19:51:32 -0700 


%% Saved with string encoding Unicode (UTF-8) 



@book{rashed.papadopoulos2017menelaus,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Menelaos},
    Booktitle = {Menelaus' \mkbibquote{Spherics}: Early translation and al-Māhānī, al-Harawī's Version},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Papadopoulos, Athanase},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {Menelaos.Spherics; mathematics.Arabic; Ibn ʿIrāq; Harawi-Mahani; ms.NewYork.Columbia.or.45},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Shorttitle = {Menelaus' \mkbibquote{Spherics}},
    Title = {Menelaus' \mkbibquote{Spherics}: Early Translation and al-Māhānī, al-Harawī's Version},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Papadopoulos, Athanase},
    Year = {2017}}

@book{nasawi:tajrid.usul.handasa:mawalidi2016,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {{al-Nasawī}, {Abū l-Ḥasan} {ʿAlī} {ibn Aḥmad}},
    Booktitle = {Kitāb al-tajrīd fī uṣūl al-handasah},
    Editor = {Mawālidī, Muṣṭafā},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Publisher = {Muʾassasat al-Furqān li-l-Turāth al-Islāmī, Markaz Dirāsāt al-Makhṭūṭāt al-Islām\iyyah{}},
    Title = {Kitāb al-tajrīd fī uṣūl al-handas\aH{}},
    Year = {2016}}

@book{khayyam:riyadiyat:rashed.vahabzadeh2005,
    Address = {Beirut},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Booktitle = {Omar Khayyam, the Mathematician},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {Khayyam.Omar; algebra},
    Publisher = {Markaz Dirāsāt al-Waḥd\aH{} al-ʿArab\iyy{}\aH{}},
    Title = {Riyāḍ\iyy{}āt ʿUmar al-Khayyām},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {2005}}

@book{khayyam:rasail:rashed.jabbar1981,
    Address = {Aleppo},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Booktitle = {Rasāʾil al-Khayyām al-jabrīyah},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Jabbār, Aḥmad},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {algebra; mathematics.Arabic; Khayyam.Omar},
    Publisher = {Jāmiʿat Ḥalab, Maʿhad al-Turāth al-ʿIlmī al-ʿArabī},
    Shorttitle = {al-Rasāʾil al-jabarīyah},
    Title = {Rasāʾil al-Khayyām al-jabr\iyy\aH{}},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Jabbār, Aḥmad},
    Year = {1981}}

@book{apollonios:conics:rashed2008,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {{Apollonios of Perga}},
    Booktitle = {Coniques},
    Date = {2008},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Title = {Apollonius de Perge, Coniques: Texte grec et arabe},
    Volumes = {multiple}}

@book{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh2000,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Booktitle = {Omar Khayyam, the Mathematician},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {Khayyam.Omar; algebra},
    Publisher = {Bibliotheca Persica Press},
    Title = {Omar Khayyam, the Mathematician},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh1999,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Booktitle = {Omar Khayyam, the Mathematician},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {Khayyam.Omar; algebra},
    Publisher = {Albert Blanchard},
    Title = {Al-Khayyam mathématicien},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{euclid:elements:arab:besthorn.heiberg1897,
    Address = {Copenhagen},
    Author = {Euclid},
    Booktitle = {Codex Leidensis 399,1: Euclidis Elementa ex interpretatione al-Hadschdschadschii cum commentariis al-Narizii},
    Editor = {Besthorn, R. O. and Heiberg, J. L.},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Shorttitle = {Elementa ex interpretatione al-Hadschdschadschii},
    Title = {Euclidis Elementa ex interpretatione al-Hadschdschadschii cum commentariis al-Narizii: Codex Leidensis 399,1},
    Year = {1897}}

@book{theodosius:sphaerica:ar.lat:kunitzsch.lorch2010,
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Author = {{Theodosius}},
    Editor = {Kunitzsch, Paul and Lorch, Richard},
    Entrysubtype = {primary},
    Keywords = {mathematics.ancient},
    Publisher = {Steiner},
    Shorttitle = {Sphaerica},
    Title = {Sphaerica: {Arabic} and {Medieval} {Latin} Translations},
    Translator = {Kunitzsch, Paul and Lorch, Richard},
    Year = {2010}}
```

## Update

Curiously, if I use a "minimal" bib file (with only the essential fields), there is no problem: all the entries are formatted correctly! Still, I have not yet been able to spot the pattern to figure out what is causing it to go wrong when I fill unessential fields...

### minimal.bib

```
@book{rashed.papadopoulos2017menelaus,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {Menelaos},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Papadopoulos, Athanase},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Title = {Menelaus' \mkbibquote{Spherics}: Early Translation and al-Māhānī, al-Harawī's Version},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Papadopoulos, Athanase},
    Year = {2017}}

@book{nasawi:tajrid.usul.handasa:mawalidi2016,
    Address = {London},
    Author = {{al-Nasawī}, {Abū l-Ḥasan} {ʿAlī} {ibn Aḥmad}},
    Editor = {Mawālidī, Muṣṭafā},
    Publisher = {Muʾassasat al-Furqān li-l-Turāth al-Islāmī, Markaz Dirāsāt al-Makhṭūṭāt al-Islām\iyyah{}},
    Title = {Kitāb al-tajrīd fī uṣūl al-handas\aH{}},
    Year = {2016}}

@book{khayyam:riyadiyat:rashed.vahabzadeh2005,
    Address = {Beirut},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Publisher = {Markaz Dirāsāt al-Waḥd\aH{} al-ʿArab\iyy{}\aH{}},
    Title = {Riyāḍ\iyy{}āt ʿUmar al-Khayyām},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {2005}}

@book{khayyam:rasail:rashed.jabbar1981,
    Address = {Aleppo},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Jabbār, Aḥmad},
    Publisher = {Jāmiʿat Ḥalab, Maʿhad al-Turāth al-ʿIlmī al-ʿArabī},
    Title = {Rasāʾil al-Khayyām al-jabr\iyy\aH{}},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Jabbār, Aḥmad},
    Year = {1981}}

@book{apollonios:conics:rashed2008,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Author = {{Apollonios of Perga}},
    Date = {2008},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi},
    Publisher = {de Gruyter},
    Title = {Apollonius de Perge, Coniques: Texte grec et arabe},
    Volumes = {multiple}}

@book{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh2000,
    Address = {New York},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Publisher = {Bibliotheca Persica Press},
    Title = {Omar Khayyam, the Mathematician},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {2000}}

@book{khayyam:math:rashed.vahabzadeh1999,
    Address = {Paris},
    Author = {Khayyam, Omar},
    Editor = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Publisher = {Albert Blanchard},
    Title = {Al-Khayyam mathématicien},
    Translator = {Rashed, Roshdi and Vahabzadeh, Bijan},
    Year = {1999}}

@book{euclid:elements:arab:besthorn.heiberg1897,
    Address = {Copenhagen},
    Author = {Euclid},
    Editor = {Besthorn, R. O. and Heiberg, J. L.},
    Title = {Euclidis Elementa ex interpretatione al-Hadschdschadschii cum commentariis al-Narizii: Codex Leidensis 399,1},
    Year = {1897}}

@book{theodosius:sphaerica:ar.lat:kunitzsch.lorch2010,
    Address = {Stuttgart},
    Author = {{Theodosius}},
    Editor = {Kunitzsch, Paul and Lorch, Richard},
    Publisher = {Steiner},
    Title = {Sphaerica: {Arabic} and {Medieval} {Latin} Translations},
    Translator = {Kunitzsch, Paul and Lorch, Richard},
    Year = {2010}}
```

Comment: The low-hanging fruit first: If you want to capitalise the "multiple volumes", say `volumes = {\autocap{m}ultiple}`.

Comment: If you don't like that kind of markup in your `.bib` file, use `\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\realautocap}{\ifcapital{\MakeCapital}{\@firstofone}}
\makeatother
\DeclareFieldFormat{volumes}{\realautocap{#1}~\bibstring{volumes}}`.

Comment: Thanks for this too! I just noticed your answer to my aside about capitalization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problematic field in your `.bib` entries is `booktitle`. Strictly speaking, `booktitle` is not a valid field for `@book` entries and you will notice that it never appears in the output, but it still turns out to have an influence on the output.

That influence of `booktitle` comes from the aptly named `editorpunct` macro defined in `chicago-notes.cbx` as

```
\newbibmacro*{editorpunct}{%
  \ifthenelse{\(\iffieldundef{booktitle}\AND%
    \iffieldundef{maintitle}\AND\iffieldundef{issuetitle}\)%
    \OR\iffieldsequal{booktitle}{title}%  Changed these for crossrefed
    \OR\iffieldsequal{maintitle}{title}}% entries.  Create problems?
  {\ifentrytype{video}% Change for Video type?  Appears
    {\newcunit\newblock}% to treat italicized title as booktitle in
    {\newunit\newblock}}% available examples.  Added issuetitle 0.9.9c.
  {\newcunit\newblock}}
```

For "normal" `@book` entries the first `\ifthenelse` is true and you get a period, but for entries with `booktitle` the test is true and you get a comma.

Since I don't know the exact and gory details of the Chicago Manual of Style  requirements here, I can't even begin to recommend a fix to this macro that satisfies CMS requirements. So here is a different workaround: Use a Biber sourcemap to completely clear out `booktitle` fields for all entries except the types `@inbook`, `@incollection`, `@inproceedings`, `@inreference` and a few others that use them.

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pernottype{inbook}
      \pernottype{incollection}
      \pernottype{inproceedings}
      \pernottype{inreference}
      \pernottype{bookinbook}
      \pernottype{audio}\pernottype{music}\pernottype{video}\pernottype{letter}
      \step[fieldset=booktitle, null]
    }
  }
}
```

You may want to contact the author of `biblatex-chicago` about this. Even though using `booktitle` in `@book` entries is arguably a user error, this behaviour is still a bit odd.

Not that it matters in `biblatex-chicago` or the standard styles, but for multi-volume books you can use the type `@mvbook` instead of `@book`.

Comment: That did it, thank you! I was afraid that solution might cause problems with `@incollection` entries that depend on a `crossref` to a `@book`, but I just tested such a case with your additional code, and it doesn't seem to cause any problems, at least for the bibliography entry.

Comment: @AlexRoberts Unlike BibTeX, Biber has fully customisable field inheritance options, which means that the `title` of a parent `@collection` gets inherited as `booktitle` to a child `@incollection`. That means that the parent never needs a `booktitle`.